# Using dplyr::filter, how can the output be limited to just first 500 rows?

Tags: r, dplyr

dplyr is a great and fast library.

Using the %>% operator enables powerful manipulation.

In my first step, I need to limit the output to only 500 rows max (for display purposes).

How can I do that?

```
par<-filter(pc,Child_Concept_GID==as.character(mcode)) %>% select(Parent_Concept_GID)
```

what I need is something like

```
filter(pc,CONDITION,rows=500)
```

Is there direct way or a nice workaround without making the first step a separate step (outside the %>% "stream")

Comment: Have you noticed the `top_n()` function in **dplyr** yet?

Comment: If you want something inside the filter, you can do `filter(pc,CONDITION, 1:n() <= 500)`

Comment: @joran I think the OP wants to display the first 500 rows, not the top 500 rows (with largest values), so I think `top_n()` would not be what he's looking for. @OP: correct me if I'm wrong

Comment: @beginneR If it's only for display purposes, I presumed the order didn't matter, but I could certainly be wrong.

Comment: What about using `head(500)`? Or am I trivializing the problem at hand.

Comment: @Ramnath from my understanding, that would be a good (maybe better) option, too. It couldn't be written inside the `filter` of course but chained with `%>%`

Comment: Any reasons you don't want to pipe? IMHO it makes for clearer code, instead of passing a zillion arguments to a single function. Just my two cents :)

Comment: OP: first 500 is what is best. But the limit is there so that renderTable to HTML does not crash with 500+ entries and uses sees a reasonable output.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

There are a couple of ways to do this.  Assuming you are pipe-lining your data (using %>%)

- `top_n(tn)` works with grouped data.  It will not return tn rows, if the data is sorted with arrange()
- `head(500)` takes the first 500 rows (can be used after arrange(), for example)
- `sample_n(size=500)` can be used to select 500 arbitrary rows

If you are looking for the R equivalent to SQL's LIMIT, use head().

Comment: FTR, it appears that `head()` can be used with a dbplyr backend to add a `LIMIT` clause too (at least with my current backend)

Comment: Note that `dplyr::sample_n` only works for local tables.  Pipes with `dbconnect` and friends won't work (at least not without pulling the entire originating table down first).

Answer (score 17):

I think you're actually looking for `slice()` here.

```
filter(pc, condition) %>% slice(1:500)
```

This does not rank the results. It merely pulls a slice, by position. In this case positions 1 through 500.

If this is coming from a relational db, `head` is a better option.

Comment: Exactly what's needed!

Answer (score 4):

To limit the output of filter, one can add after filter a function

```
top_n()
```

credit goes to commenter joran

solution

```
par<-filter(pc,Child_Concept_GID==as.character(mcode)) %>% top_n(500) %>% select(Parent_Concept_GID)
```

Comment: Note that if you are hooking up to a database this is almost certainly not what you want (Assuming you are trying to do the equivalent of TOP n or LIMIT n). top_n() actually forces a rank operation on the whole table, which if your table is big will take a long time.  There is not actually an implementation of LIMIT because this is inconsistent across databases (see https://github.com/hadley/dplyr/issues/1087).

Answer (score 0):

you can use first(500).  x %>% first(500). this seems the easiest